# R markdown pdf output figure with out.width='90%' generating the wrong path with the render function and output_dir used

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown

I am generating a pdf from an Rmd file with output = pdf and xelatex.
Some figures are large and cover the entire page. So the generated pdf creates an empty page. To avoid that I decided to reduce the size of the figure using out.width='90%'.

Here is my .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "test out width"
author: "Courvoisier"
date: "8 November 2016"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_height: 8
    fig_width: 12
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Including Plots

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE, out.width='90%'}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I used render to create the pdf. Here is the .R code:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

RmdFile = "testoutwidth.Rmd"
outputpdfFilePathoutPdf = "testoutwidth.pdf"
renderoutputpdfFilePath = render(input = RmdFile, output_file = outputpdfFilePathoutPdf)
```

This works fine and creates the following .TeX code for the figures:

```
\includegraphics{testoutwidth_files/figure-latex/pressure-1.pdf}

\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{testoutwidth_files/figure-latex/pressure2-1}
```

However, when choosing an output_dir in the render function such as:

```
renderoutputpdfFilePath = render(input = RmdFile, output_dir = "out pdf/", output_file = outputpdfFilePathoutPdf)
```

The includegraphics commands in the .TeX generated become

```
\includegraphics{C:/work/testRenderRmd/out pdf/testoutwidth_files/figure-latex/pressure-1.pdf}

\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{C:\work\testRenderRmd\out pdf\testoutwidth_files/figure-latex/pressure2-1}
```

In the second \includegraphics (the one that has [width=0.9\linewidth]) the path separators are "\" instead of "/" and so the latex compilation fails. (it gives C:\work... instead of C:/work/... ).

What should I use to solve this?

thanks

Note: it seems there is an issue open about this on the rmarkdown github :
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/808

Comment: You should post the actual code and if you can the error part too!

Comment: Indeed, I also figured that this is only for the render function when using output_dir.

Comment: I have always used the knit button in the Markdown console on Rstudio to do this job, so this is more speculative than I would prefer. But have you considered  setting a figure path in the chunk options: `fig.path='C:/work/testRenderRmd/out pdf/testoutwidth_files/figure-latex/ `for the chunks...it should coerce it to put that last file in the right spot with the whole path in play. Also, consider getting rid of the space in `out pdf/` use `camelCase` or under_score to fill that gap, just because spaces are scary :).

Comment: Thanks @bethanyP: Coercing fig.path in the chunk that uses `out.width='90%'` solves the problem :). But it's not really a permanent solution. It does not offer the flexibility of being able to change the output dir on the fly, which the point of using render.
Yes, spaces should be used with caution. In this case though they don't cause a problem.

Comment: Just for the record: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/808#issuecomment-259079236 (sorry, I'm not really helpful)